# How to get notified if a object is garbage collected?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, garbage-collection, observer-pattern

## Short version:

For a cache class I need to get notified if an object is garbage collected (to remove the according entries from my cache). What is the best way to do so? Sending an event from the destructor?

## Long version:

I am writing a cacher/memoizer for functions that take one huge parameter-tree object and many small value type parameters, e.g.,

```
double myFunc(HugeParTree parTree, int dynPar1, double dynPar2)
```

I want to cache these functions in the following way:

- Cache results for the tuples (parTree.GUID, dynPar1, dynPar2, ...)
- Whenever `parTree` changes, which seldomly happens, all according cache entries are deleted (via Observer pattern). (`parTree.Equals()` is just too expensive; it compares 100+ value types).

Code looks like this right now (for one value parameter):

```
public class CachedFunction1ObsPar1Par<TRet, TObsPar1, TPar1>
        where TObsPar1 : IObservable, IProvideGUID
    {
        public delegate TRet ValueCalculator(TObsPar1 obsPar1, TPar1 par1);

        public CachedFunction1ObsPar1Par(ValueCalculator calc)
        {
            _calc = calc;
        }


        #region members

        private ValueCalculator _calc;

        private Dictionary<Guid, Dictionary<TPar1, TRet>> _cache = 
            new Dictionary<Guid, Dictionary<TPar1,TRet>>();

        #endregion


        public TRet value(TObsPar1 obsPar1, TPar1 par1)
        {
            TRet result;
            bool cacheHit = checkCache(obsPar1, par1, out result);

            if (cacheHit)
            {
                Debug.Assert(result.Equals(_calc(obsPar1, par1)));
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                result = _calc(obsPar1, par1);
                _cache[obsPar1.GUID].Add(par1, result);
                return result;
            }
        }

        private bool checkCache(TObsPar1 obsPar1, TPar1 par1, out TRet result)
        {
            if (!_cache.ContainsKey(obsPar1.GUID))
            {
                _cache.Add(obsPar1.GUID, new Dictionary<TPar1, TRet>());
                obsPar1._changed += this.invalidateCache;
            }

            Dictionary<TPar1, TRet> guidCache = _cache[obsPar1.GUID];

            bool success = guidCache.TryGetValue(par1, out result);

            return success;
        }

        private void invalidateCache(object sender)
        {
            TObsPar1 obsPar = (TObsPar1)sender;

            _cache.Remove(obsPar.GUID);

            obsPar._changed -= this.invalidateCache;
        }
    }
```

I haven't tested this yet, as I still have the problem that cache entries never get removed after the according parTree is not used any more. I'd love a synchronous solution without repeated "scans" for very old cache entries.

Comment: But if you keep objects referenced in a cache, garbage collection would not reach them. It's reversed: first you remove a reference from the cache, THEN the object is garbage collected.

Comment: There is an article on MSDN about [Garbage Collection Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713687.aspx), which might prove useful.

Comment: @Humberto I am actually holding a GUID to the object in the cache.

Comment: @B3ret sorry about that. I think I gave too much emphasis on the short version of the problem!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> For a cache class I need to get notified if an object is garbage
>   collected (to remove the according entries from my cache). What is the
>   best way to do so? Sending an event from the destructor?

If your cache holds normal (strong) references the items will never be collected.

If your cache holds WeakReferences you do not have to remove anything.

Comment: You should remove the dead `WeakReference`s from time to time. Otherwise they will just litter your memory.

Comment: I am not actually holding the object in the cache, I am holding its Guid. I am thinking of holding a Guid->WeakReference<Object> SortedList and remove guids with null-Values from time to time

Comment: I marked this as answer, at it gets closest to solving my problem. I guess I will create a `SortedList<WeakReference<TObsPar1>, Guid>` and check for null references from time to time. I came up with the destructor approach below, but figured it to be too unreliable and slow.

Answer (score 2):

Henk already mentioned the flaw in your requirement.

But, just to answer your question.
To know when an object is being garbage collected you can write a destructor for that object.

```
~YourClass();
```

As per MSDN:

> This method is automatically called after an object becomes
>   inaccessible

Though it's never recommended to rely on GC or destructor.

Comment: Correct but a dtor is a) unreliable and b) expensive

Comment: I did already included the disclaimer! Not sure why got a downvote!

Answer (score 1):

You could define an interface 'ICacheable' that must be implemented by the objects in the cache. In a method of the interface `RemoveFromCache()` you could search the cache for its child objects and remove them.

When you remove an item from the cache, test it for the interface and call `RemoveFromCache()`.

This is similar to IDisposable.

Garbage collection is not something to count on because you never know when it will run.